# Speed up look ahead, behind time-series search in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a pandas DataFrame comprising items from an e-commerce site. I'm checking whether or not items still exist in the data frame on either subsequent (look ahead) or previous (behind) days, with a function like this:

```
#get a unique set of product urls for the next 2 days. If the current row's URL is in that set, mark it as 0 (not expiring); otherwise mark it 1 (expiring).

def is_expiring_product(row):
    if row.childurl in df[(df['date'] > row['date']) & (df['date'] < (row['date']  + np.timedelta64(2,"D")) ) ].childurl.unique():
        row.is_expiring_product = 0
    else:
        row.is_expiring_product = 1
    return row
```

The problem is that this takes ages (24 hours+, if it ever completes) to apply to a frame of 1M+ records.

Intuition tells me there must be a more performant method for this...

Maybe creating a separate DataFrame of unique URLs for each day, then seeking on that DataFrame instead of the larger frame? I'm not sure why that would be any faster though...

Comment: Can you add some sample data we can copy/paste, and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Example of code #1: Compute *is_expiring_product* for a single date

For the test I used the following DataFrame (*date* column is of type *datetime64[ns]*):

```
        date  url
0 2019-09-10  Xxx
1 2019-09-12  Xxx
2 2019-09-14  Xxx
3 2019-09-11  Yyy
4 2019-09-12  Yyy
5 2019-09-12  Zz1
6 2019-09-12  Zz2
7 2019-09-08  Ttt
8 2019-09-12  Ttt
9 2019-09-15  Ttt
```

The starting point is to define 2 variables, used in cutting of *df*,
by *date*, into bins (*Past*, *Today* and *Future*):

```
dMin = pd.to_datetime(0)            # "Minimal" date
dMax = pd.to_datetime('2050-12-31') # "Maximal" date
```

Assume that we want to compute *is_expiring_product* only for *2019-09-12*,
so the first thing is to set *currDate* (will also be used in cutting):

```
currDate = pd.to_datetime('2019-09-12')
```

Then add *is_expiring_product* column, initially filled with empty strings:

```
df = df.assign(is_expiring_product='')
```

Compute *bucket* - the result of cutting dates into bins:

```
bucket = pd.cut(df.date, bins = [dMin, currDate - pd.offsets.Day(1),
    currDate, dMax], labels=['Past', 'Today', 'Future'])
```

The next step is to compute *df_current* - a subset of rows for the
"current" date:

```
df_current = df[bucket == 'Today']
```

To generate indices of *url*s in rows for "other" dates, run:

```
ind_other = pd.Index(df[bucket.isin(['Past', 'Future'])].url.unique())
```

And the last step is to generate values for *is_expiring_product* and
update this column:

```
df.is_expiring_product.update((~df_current.url.isin(ind_other)).astype(int))
```

The result is:

```
        date  url is_expiring_product
0 2019-09-10  Xxx                    
1 2019-09-12  Xxx                   0
2 2019-09-14  Xxx                    
3 2019-09-11  Yyy                    
4 2019-09-12  Yyy                   0
5 2019-09-12  Zz1                   1
6 2019-09-12  Zz2                   1
7 2019-09-08  Ttt                    
8 2019-09-12  Ttt                   0
9 2019-09-15  Ttt
```

Description of results:

- Non-empty values are for *2019-09-12*.
- Index == *1*, *4* and *12*: *0* - These *url*s (*Xxx*, *Yyy* and *Ttt*)
  are present on other dates.
- Index == *5* and *6*: *1* - These *url*s (*Zz1* and *Zz2*) are not
  present on other dates.

## Example of code #2: Compute *is_expiring_product* for all dates

The source DataFrame is the same, start from defining *dMin* and *dMax*
as before.

Then define the following function to set the expiration status:

```
def setExpired(grp):
    currDate = grp.name    # Grouping key
    bucket = pd.cut(df.date, bins = [dMin, currDate - pd.offsets.Day(1),
        currDate, dMax], labels=['Past', 'Current', 'Future'])
    df_current = df[bucket == 'Current']
    ind_other = pd.Index(df[bucket.isin(['Past', 'Future'])].url.unique())
    res = (~df_current.url.isin(ind_other)).astype(int)
    return res
```

And the whole computing boils down to a **single** instruction,
applicating this function to each group (for each date):

```
df['is_expiring_product'] = df.groupby('date').apply(setExpired).droplevel(0)
```

The additional call to *droplevel(0)* is required, because the result of
*apply* has a **MultiIndex** with:

- level 0 - grouping dates,
- level 1 - keys of each *Series* returned by calls to *setExpired*.

So in order to save it in *df* (using "ordinary" index), the top level
of the MultiIndex must be dropped.

This time the result is:

```
        date  url  is_expiring_product
0 2019-09-10  Xxx                    0
1 2019-09-12  Xxx                    0
2 2019-09-14  Xxx                    0
3 2019-09-11  Yyy                    0
4 2019-09-12  Yyy                    0
5 2019-09-12  Zz1                    1
6 2019-09-12  Zz2                    1
7 2019-09-08  Ttt                    0
8 2019-09-12  Ttt                    0
9 2019-09-15  Ttt                    0
```

## Yet another, simpler and quicker solution

Note that there is no need to compute *is_expiring_product* for
each row separately.

Much simpler and quicker, totally different solution is to:

- compute *is_expiring_product* for **each url** (without repetitions),
- then save the result in all rows containing this *url*.

This solution works as follows:

- Group rows by *url*.
- For each group:

  - take *date* column,
  - check whether all dates are the same,
  - if the are, return *1* (this *url* occurs only on a **single** date),
  - otherwise return *0* (this *url* occurs on **multiple** dates).
- "Expand" this result on each row containing this *url*.
- Save the result in *is_expiring_product* column.

The whole above action can be saved as a **single** instruction:

```
df['is_expiring_product'] = df.groupby('url').date\
    .transform(lambda grp: 1 if grp.unique().size == 1 else 0)
```

with the same result as before.

Please write a comment, how long did it take to execute the above
instruction on your DataFrame and how many rows it has.